# Rails 3 - Application layout questions

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, mootools

I'm having some difficulties getting my head around Rails' general application layout.

Basically, I am making a web app for football plays. Coaches login and get brought to the /coach/index page. On that page they can draw their play and such, using a JavaScript front end. My problem is, in order to save the play, I need to send that JSON to the server, to log it in the right Play database entry.

1. Is my layout correct, logically? As in, should a coach logging in bring him to that page, and then he draws the plays there and saves them, creates new ones, loads them etc, or should I be doing this on the pages governed by the Play controller?
2. I want to save the JSON generated by the play drawing engine to the database. What's the best way to go about doing this? All the Rails AJAX tutorials I see are based on simple forms where you set the remote => true property on them and such. How do I make an AJAX POST/GET to the Rails DB without an explicit form, and handle the input?
3. This is probably down to my lack of Rails know-how (I'm trying to learn as I go), but what, in your more experienced view, is the best way for me to ensure the right plays get shown to the coach who made them? I'm struggling a little in understanding how controllers access things controlled by other controllers. I'm sure there must be some conventions for this kind of thing.

The more I think about it, the more it seems to me that logging in should take you to the /plays directory, and I should be modifying the create and such in there in order to do what I want to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another thing I wanted to ask: How do I have a hidden entry on a submission to a database - As in, when someone sets up a new Play, I want it to be associated with that user without them having to explicitly say that. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is your layout logical? `/coaches` makes sense as a destination for Coaches that log in. If your application users are only coaches, then even the root makes sense. When a Coach logs in, he's going to some form of `coaches#show`, but that doesn't mean you're doing something wrong just because the URL is something like `/profile`. Not everything needs to adhere to full REST.on the URL side. In the real world, not ever `new` action resides on its own little quaint page. If it makes sense to nest a new Play form on the `/coaches` page, your URL doesn't need to reflect it.

Controllers control interactions with a resource. From the `/coaches` page, you'll still be sending delete play requests to `plays#destroy` and validating new plays through `plays#create` which can `render 'coaches/index' when it fails.`

1. I've never really dealt with AJAX in Rails.
2. The best way to ensure that Coaches only see their own plays is to scope them through the `Coach has_many :plays` association. The convention in Rails authentication solutions (like Devise) is to provide a method `current_user` which returns an instance of the User model of the user that's current logged in.

Your `coaches#index` action could look like:

```
# Coaches controller
def index
  @plays = current_user.plays
end
```

Then your view could have:

```
# views/coaches/index.erb
<ul>
<% for play in @plays %>
  <li><%= play.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

What you wouldn't do: `@plays = Play.where(:user_id => @user.id)`.

It also simplifies and secures other actions. Consider:

```
@play = current_user.plays.new

@play = current_user.plays.build(:name => "My First Play")
redirect_to @play, :notice => "Success!" if @play.save

current_user.plays.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

To answer your question added as a comment:

```
# Coaches controller
def new
  @play = current_user.plays.new
end

def create
  @play = current_user.plays.build(params[:play]) # @play now already contains the association to the coach that created it.
  if @play.save!
    redirect_to # somewhere
  else
    render 'coaches/index'
  end
end
```

- I highly recommend [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) if you aren't familiar with them. Even watching episodes on topics you're not going to implement anytime soon will give you good exposure.
- For example, here's a [Railscast on Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise). Devise also has decent documentation on [Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).
- I recently bought CodeSchool's couse on [Rals Best Practices](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-best-practices). Even though some of it might be beyond your immediate grasp, it's a resource that you can always revisit. I consult the slides that came with it all the time to look for better ways of doing things.

Comment: Thanks a million @Dobry, that was an awesome answer. A lot of good stuff in there to think about, and thank you for the links. I am familiar with Rails for Zombie's but I didn't realise they had a more advanced tutorial set out - very nice!